# Should a 3-field <select> date input use fieldset for grouping?

Tags: usability, forms, accessibility, input-fields, html

I am trying to do the best for usability and accessibility

I use `fieldset` to group `input` radio-button and checkbox elements.

When I have a date input that is actually 3 select dropdown fields, one for day, one for month and one for year, should I use fieldset to group them?

Comment: I am not sure what part of UX you are trying to address or I am missing something.Please try to be more specific if possible. 

Here is a link about from structuring which might help you get some idea on it. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form

Hope if helps :)

Comment: Updated about the reason for the grouping - 3 select fields for day, month, year

Comment: Is the concern related to whether or not to have multiple date input fields or how well can they be presented to provide better UX or is the question really about using <fieldset> or not? Because using <fieldset> or not is more related to writing and organizing HTML code and not much about UX.. Or am I missing anything..

Answer (score 2):

Well,  tag is used to group related elements in a form - so yes.

You can also take usage of legend and label inside your fieldset, i.e.:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Date</legend>
    <label><select><option value=".....</select> Day</label>
    <label><select><option value=".....</select> Month</label>
    ...
```

See also:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-fieldset-element
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741328/why-do-we-need-a-fieldset-tag

Answer (score 0):

Yes `<fieldset>` should be used for grouping inputs for text, radio-dials, checkboxes and
**other related content that should be grouped together**
so this would include both input and select elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes fieldset is better option as it allows you to group set of fields and also allows you to mark up your data.